# re code the categorical column using sub setting the data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I am trying to recode the categorical column of a pandas dataframe to a more sensible categorical column.

For simplicity i am taking the titanic data which has the "Cabin" column. I am trying to combine all A10 A20 A22 and recode it to A, similarly C10,C12 to C and so on so forth.

I already tried using the subset and here is my code.

```
for i in ['A','B','C']:
    for x in train[train.Cabin.str.contains(i)].loc[:,'Cabin'].index:
        train.loc[x,'Cabin'] = i
```

What i am looking for is an efficient way of doing it. I am a newbie and i think this is not the right approach.  please guide me. I am sorry if i have violated any rule of stack-overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If possible, extract first letter from column:

```
train.Cabin = train.Cabin.str[0]
```

Or if need extract first matched value from list:

```
L = ['A','B','C']

pat = '|'.join(L)
train.Cabin = train.Cabin.str.extract('('+ pat + ')', expand=False)
```

Comment: thankyou this is a unique approach, could you please explain the use of   '|'

Comment: @AnanyaPandey - Sure, it is regex `OR` - it means it extract `A or B or C`